# How to find values between date ranges Power BI?

Tags: sql, powerbi, ssas

I need help to understand a thing.

I have a table that uses slow changing dimension, with start and end date and indicator if it is active or not:

| Type | start | end | value | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0001/01/01 | 9999/12/31 | 10 | 1 |
| B | 2015/03/18 | 2016-06-25 | 4 | 0 |
| B | 2016-06-25 | 9999/12/31 | 7 | 1 |
| C | 2017-05-07 | 9999/12/31 | 8 | 1 |

I need to connect this table to a report in power bi and fetch the respective value in a line graph that brings the values by month.

Something like this:
[image]

I am using a report connect to SSAS through Direct Query. I am able to create a view with the new structure to connect to my cube.

How can I get this result using a table with this structure.

Thanks for the help!

I thought about creating a table with a value for each month, but as you can see, I have dates ranging from 0001-01-01 to 9999-12-31. (To be honest, I don't really know how to do that either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the chart, assume that date range is `2016-04` ~ `2017-12`, so

1. Generate a `month` dimension for the above date range
2. Cross join `month` dimension and the give slow changing dimension `slo_dim` and get `value` in effective period
3. Draw a line chart based on the result from step 2

```sql
with cte_month (year_month, n) as (
select cast('2016-04-01' as date), 1 
union all
select dateadd(month, 1, year_month), n+1
  from cte_month
 where n < 21)
select d.type,
       m.year_month,
       d.value
  from cte_month m, slo_dim d
 where m.year_month between d.start_dt and d.end_dt
 order by d.type, m.year_month;
```

Result:

```
type|year_month|value|
----+----------+-----+
A   |2016-04-01|   10|
A   |2016-05-01|   10|
A   |2016-06-01|   10|
A   |2016-07-01|   10|
A   |2016-08-01|   10|
A   |2016-09-01|   10|
A   |2016-10-01|   10|
A   |2016-11-01|   10|
A   |2016-12-01|   10|
A   |2017-01-01|   10|
A   |2017-02-01|   10|
A   |2017-03-01|   10|
A   |2017-04-01|   10|
A   |2017-05-01|   10|
A   |2017-06-01|   10|
A   |2017-07-01|   10|
A   |2017-08-01|   10|
A   |2017-09-01|   10|
A   |2017-10-01|   10|
A   |2017-11-01|   10|
A   |2017-12-01|   10|
B   |2016-04-01|    4|
B   |2016-05-01|    4|
B   |2016-06-01|    4|
B   |2016-07-01|    7|
B   |2016-08-01|    7|
B   |2016-09-01|    7|
B   |2016-10-01|    7|
B   |2016-11-01|    7|
B   |2016-12-01|    7|
B   |2017-01-01|    7|
B   |2017-02-01|    7|
B   |2017-03-01|    7|
B   |2017-04-01|    7|
B   |2017-05-01|    7|
B   |2017-06-01|    7|
B   |2017-07-01|    7|
B   |2017-08-01|    7|
B   |2017-09-01|    7|
B   |2017-10-01|    7|
B   |2017-11-01|    7|
B   |2017-12-01|    7|
C   |2017-06-01|    8|
C   |2017-07-01|    8|
C   |2017-08-01|    8|
C   |2017-09-01|    8|
C   |2017-10-01|    8|
C   |2017-11-01|    8|
C   |2017-12-01|    8|
```